# how do i test if the left or right side of my screen is being touched in libgdx

Tags: java, android, mobile, libgdx

How do I test if the left or right side of my screen is being touched in libgdx?

So I would like to be able to test if the left or right side of my
screen is being touched. If the left side is it would do something, and if the right side is it would do something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code in your game loop:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
    if (Gdx.input.getX() < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2){
        //left
    } else {
        //right
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok i will jest ask you this to do you know how to make it so that you can click more than tow parts of the screen to do stuff